# Can't setup ssh on local

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, bitbucket

I've tried setting up a ssh key. Following instructions on bitbucket and ubuntu.com, specifically.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

However, when I try to check it's installed ok entering.

```
ssh -v
```

I get the response.

```
ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
       [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
       [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
       [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
       [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
       [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]
       [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
       [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

But according to Bitbucket the first line should be version details.

```
$ ssh -v 
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] etc etc...
```

It also states

> If you have  ssh  installed, the terminal returns version information.

Is there something I am missing here?  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, on a Macbook.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that:

ssh -v is:

> -v      Verbose mode.  Causes ssh to print debugging messages about
>   its
>                progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentica-
>                tion, and configuration problems.  Multiple -v options increase
>                the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.

and ssh -V:

> -V      Display the version number and exit.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember that.  On the bitbucket instruction is has lowercase, the output shows the version number.  When I use -V I can see it is installed.  Confused as to why my output is different to that on the guides.  At least I know that ssh is in fact installed = the problems I have connecting to bitbucket aren't down to this.

Answer (score 2):

Small v means verbose; big V is version

```
ssh -V
```